# Cheat sheet for music theory - where can I find it?

Tags: theory, chords, rhythm, abc-notation

Is there a downloadable cheat sheet for music theory? (about basic terms and nomenclatura)

Edit:  ... as basic information for absolute beginners, like I gave to pupils of secondary school. Maybe for different levels like high-school, too.

e.g. scales, triads, Circle of Fifths, basic terms of chord progression.

Comment: I wonder what is wrong of this question. I haven’t known the term *cheat sheet* until now and I’m sure some posters like these I’ve mentioned in my answer would be quite helpful and on the other hand they will evoke many questions! I would have been happy if someone here had told about a year ago that something like this exists. This would have saved me from looking up 100 of wiki pages to find the correct terms. Obvious English speaking people have no idea how difficult it is for foreigners to find the correct translation for music terms like e.g. relativ and parallel chords and many others.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I'm curious as to the scope of the question. What should such a sheet cover? Key signatures? Scales and intervals? Just translations of terms? Modulation? Schenkerian analysis? Set theory? Transformational theory? Theories of early music? Different tuning systems throughout history? I worry that such a cheat sheet quickly just becomes a book!

Comment: @ Richard: Ok, I’ll write it more precisely: basic information for absolute beginners, like I gave to  pupils  of secondary school. Maybe for different levels like high-school, too. I will poste later my own, if I’ll found it ;)

Comment: This seems too broad, for one. Plenty of these resources exist, but no "cheat sheet" can provide everything about music theory. Plus, this seems to be a recommendation for specific equipment, whoch would render it off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for external resources are off-topic.

Comment: What is broad here? The question could simply be answered by **yes** and adding a picture or a link. I‘m still convinced that it is a smart idea to have some of. this information on your keyboard or near your guitar or as I‘m proposing as book bezel.

Comment: They're not a cheat sheets per se, but I frequently refer to these 2 wikipedia overviews of [chord progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_progression) (for the lists/definitions of the idiomatic ones), and for [modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)) (to double-check for the appropriate harmonizations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests for resources are supposed to be off topic, so you got some downvotes.

Nevertheless, this is one of my favorite cheat sheet(s)

https://tobyrush.com/theorypages/en-uk/index.html

Comment: I‘ve seen this one too, but it might be toooooo broad, you could paper  all four walls of your room. But as it so broad  it must very fine to my to broad question. Accepted! ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several posters available that show the most important information for beginners like these:

[image]

https://www.adsrsounds.com/music-theory-tutorials/music-theory-cheat-sheet/

https://www.pinterest.ch/pin/592504894698030594/

and surely many others! Print them out and oin them on the wall ahead of you computer or use it as cover or protection envelope of you song books and study books.

Comment: I wouldn't call these relevant to "theory" but rather that they are quick reference sheets for nomenclature.

Comment: @ Carl: Pupils and students, for whom this Site seems to be thought call everything that is not practice like singing playing instruments **Theory**. I don’t think that anyone of all those who are asking  here questions about “elementary theory” like guitar chords, ledger lines, clefs, signs etc. could do anything with the term or tag nomenclature.